# How to draw and recognize gesture using gesture overlay view

Tags: android, gesture, android-gesture

I do not know Why I am getting error and getting my app crash saying index out of bound. I have made three different question but none of them help. So here I am saving my basic idea.

I think there is no need to share the code, All I want to draw the gesture on the `gestureOverlayView` are the points given below

1. if the gesture is the right gesture Say Letter **A** then it should stay visible if not then it should  disappear as it does every time.
2. If the user has made the right gesture then the gesture should not be disappear , but there is a reset button , when the user made the correct gesture and let say it is not disappear then when user click on the Reset Button then the `gestureOverlayView` Should be removed

So Please kindly guide me how can I made gesture permanent after when it is the gesture we wanted user to made and then if it is our desired gesture and successfully made it permanent then how to reset it on the reset button

Please guide me and help me

Comment: "I think there is no need to share the code": this is wrong if you want help with the index out of bound exception.

Comment: You are right , but I said to share the idea how to persistent the drawing of the gesture and secondly How to remove it manually , i Just want these two points